# File Monitoring Daemon on Unix

Tags: unix, scripting, daemon, fedora

I am looking to write a file monitoring daemon that runs on Fedora 8 that monitors a file and reports back when the file was last modified in minutes.

What would be the best way to do this, Im a bit of a newbie in terms of writing daemons like this?

I guess I write a script? and then run this using a daemon. If anyone has any links to point me in the right direction it would be helpful :)

Comment: fedora 8 is very old and unsecure. Please update to Fedora 14 or Fedora 15 alpha.

Comment: @bioinfornatics  how is upgrading to an alpha making things more secure?  security comes from stability, not obscurity

Comment: @bioinfornatics...didnt ask for any advice on what operating system to use, its a legacy system and its staying that way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My choice would be to use the cron job manager. So you write a program in the language of your choice that monitors that file and reports whatever you need. Then program your cron to execute that program as often as you whant (daily, weekle, every minute...).

Cron is easy to use, [here](http://www.tutorial5.com/content/view/95/51/), a tutorial.   :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [iwatch](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html) It allows you to fire off jobs only when things change, you don't have to continuously check them with cron.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [inotify tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/) for that. And get a more recent Fedora version, 8 is few years old.

Comment: as it says in the comment of my post this is a legacy system. I am not in charge of what Os is being run on it I just need to get some info from it for another application :)