# Setting up a Daemon in Unix

Tags: unix, daemon, aix

I have scheduled a crontab job in AIX 6.1 OS to run twice in an hour which runs for the whole day to process a load.

The load which crontab kicks off needs files to arrive at a particular directory and if the files arrive, I process them.

It so happens that for the 24 times the crontab kicks off my load there would be only 7 times I actually receive the files and for the rest of the times I receive no files and the load reports saying that no files received and I cannot preict when files arrive as it can arrive anytime.

I heard that a DAEMON can be setup in Unix which can monitor for files arriving at a particular destination and call other scripts after that.

I was thinking if it were possible to create a daemon to monitor a particular destination and if files are present, It can call a shell script.

Is this possible, if yes how can I code the daemon. I have no prior experience with daemons. Can anyone clarify.

Comment: It sounds as if you've heard of inotify on Linux; that is designed to alert a process when a directory changes (e.g. because a file arrives) and other similar events.  In the absence of a similar system, you can write a process that periodically scans the directory and sees what has changed since the last scan (new files created, old files removed, files changed — whatever you need).  The only benefit of a daemon over a separate script is that the daemon can keep a record of the state at the last scan.  Yes, it's straight-forward to code up a daemon that does what you want.

Comment: Since there are a 1000 other questions with the daemon tag, there are bound to be some that answer this question for you.  I see four probably relevant questions in the 'Related' list at right: [How do I daemonize an arbitrary script in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525247/), [File Monitoring Daemon on Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311274/), [Writing a Unix Daemon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243917/) and [Daemons in C — is there a way they're meant to be implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025029/).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler : Thanks for the comments. I get that I can create a secondary script that runs every minute or something like that and call my actual script only if files are present which will give the effect of daemon but is there a way to run my secondary script a background job instead of scheduling in cron. I went through the links you provided but could not get sense of how I can do that. At the end of the day I want to stay away from cron.

Comment: The first link seems to discuss your situation pretty accurately.  You want to daemonize a script; it explains how to do it. You wrap the body of the script in a `while true; do ...; done` loop.  You run it via `nohup` after sending the output where you want it to go.  That's the long and the short of it.  If you're willing to delve into C, then I have a `daemonize` program that I wrote to run another program (that didn't daemonize itself properly) as a true daemon.  Then I got the bug in the other program fixed so I didn't have as much need for it any more. See my profile for contact info.

Comment: See also [Is there a good reason to write my own `daemonize()` function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720439/is-there-a-good-reason-to-write-my-own-daemonize-function-instead-of-using-daemo/3720789#3720789)  There are a couple of good links in [Creating and using a C/C++ Daemon on Linux or Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323304/creating-and-using-linux-unix-c-c-daemon/) — the link to the TED talk is not directly relevant, but is interesting.